# Group values of an object in a new array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to return an array with multiple elements pulled from an array of objects.

This is de original object:

```
    data: Array(11)
       0: {id: "1", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-01", PD_PETROLEO: 369.168, PD_GAS: 96, …}
       1: {id: "2", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-02", PD_PETROLEO: 364.21, PD_GAS: 96, …}
       2: {id: "3", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-03", PD_PETROLEO: 361.559, PD_GAS: 96, …}
       3: {id: "4", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-04", PD_PETROLEO: 322.346, PD_GAS: 81, …}
       4: {id: "5", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-05", PD_PETROLEO: 339.027, PD_GAS: 44, …}
       5: {id: "6", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-06", PD_PETROLEO: 346.939, PD_GAS: 44, …}
       6: {id: "7", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-08", PD_PETROLEO: 321.934, PD_GAS: 44, …}
       7: {id: "8", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-09", PD_PETROLEO: 351.404, PD_GAS: 44, …}
       8: {id: "9", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 360.167, PD_GAS: 44, …}
       9: {id: "10", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 371.895, PD_GAS: 44, …}
      10: {id: "11", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-11", PD_PETROLEO: 356.232, PD_GAS: 66, …}
```

I'm using the map function like this:

```
    const FECHA_DATA = [
       datosDiarios &&
       datosDiarios.data.map(fecha => {
          const { FECHA, PD_GAS, PD_AGUA, PD_PETROLEO } = fecha;
          return FECHA;
       }),
    ];
```

And I'm getting this result:

```
    [Array(11)]
       0: (11) ["2010-06-01", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-06", "2010-06-08", "2010-06-09", "2010-06-1..."]
```

But, I need the array to be like this for PD_GAS, PD_PETROLEO, and PD_AGUA:

```
    [Array(11)]
       0: (11) ["2010-06-01", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-06", "2010-06-08", "2010-06-09", "2010-06-1..."],
       1: (11) [96, 96, 96, 81, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 66],
       2: (11) [1138.48, 1138.48, 1138.48, 1146.85, 1160.95, 1160.95, 1160.95, 1160.95, 1160.95, 1160.95, 1157.58],
       3: (11) [369.168, 364.21, 361.559, 322.346, 339.027, 346.939, 321.934, 351.404, 360.167, 371.895, 356.232],
```

I think that with the function map it is possible but if someone has another way to do this, I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of map you need to use reduce

```
const data = [
        {id: "1", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-01", PD_PETROLEO: 369.168, PD_GAS: 96}, 
       {id: "2", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-02", PD_PETROLEO: 364.21, PD_GAS: 96},
       {id: "3", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-03", PD_PETROLEO: 361.559, PD_GAS: 96},
       {id: "4", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-04", PD_PETROLEO: 322.346, PD_GAS: 81},
       {id: "5", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-05", PD_PETROLEO: 339.027, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "6", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-06", PD_PETROLEO: 346.939, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "7", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-08", PD_PETROLEO: 321.934, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "8", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-09", PD_PETROLEO: 351.404, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "9", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 360.167, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "10", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 371.895, PD_GAS: 44},
      {id: "11", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-11", PD_PETROLEO: 356.232, PD_GAS: 66}];

const result = data.reduce((acc,item) => {
    const { FECHA, PD_GAS, PD_AGUA, PD_PETROLEO } = item;
    acc[0].push(FECHA);
    acc[1].push(PD_GAS);
    acc[2].push(PD_AGUA);
    acc[3].push(PD_PETROLEO );

    return acc;
}, [[],[],[],[]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, with the destructuring it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JimmyMontes yeah, but you already accepted another answer without destructing, at least you can upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason `.map()` is not working is because mapping an array produces a 1->1 result from your original dataset. It looks like you want a 4->1 result, where for every record in the original data, you want to produce an entry in 4 arrays. The easiest way to do this would probably be with the `.reduce()` function instead, like so:

```js
let data = [{id: "1", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-01", PD_PETROLEO: 369.168, PD_GAS: 96},
{id: "2", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-02", PD_PETROLEO: 364.21, PD_GAS: 96},
{id: "3", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-03", PD_PETROLEO: 361.559, PD_GAS: 96},
{id: "4", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-04", PD_PETROLEO: 322.346, PD_GAS: 81},
{id: "5", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-05", PD_PETROLEO: 339.027, PD_GAS: 44},
{id: "6", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-06", PD_PETROLEO: 346.939, PD_GAS: 44},
{id: "7", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-08", PD_PETROLEO: 321.934, PD_GAS: 44},
{id: "8", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-09", PD_PETROLEO: 351.404, PD_GAS: 44},
{id: "9", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 360.167, PD_GAS: 44},
{id: "10", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 371.895, PD_GAS: 44},
{id: "11", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-11", PD_PETROLEO: 356.232, PD_GAS: 66}];

let mappedData = data.reduce((res, curr) => {
  // push whatever property you want to each spot in the array
  // you can change the order however you'd like
  res[0].push(curr.COMPLETAMIENTO);
  res[1].push(curr.FECHA);
  res[2].push(curr.PD_PETROLEO);
  res[3].push(curr.PD_GAS);
  return res;
}, [[], [], [], []]); // start with an array of 4 empty arrays into which we can push our values

console.log(mappedData)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not work here, because you need to rotate the matrix.

You could take an array of keys in the wanted order and push to the same index as the keys.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-01", PD_PETROLEO: 369.168, PD_GAS: 96 }, { id: "2", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-02", PD_PETROLEO: 364.21, PD_GAS: 96 }, { id: "3", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-03", PD_PETROLEO: 361.559, PD_GAS: 96 }, { id: "4", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-04", PD_PETROLEO: 322.346, PD_GAS: 81 }, { id: "5", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-05", PD_PETROLEO: 339.027, PD_GAS: 44 }, { id: "6", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-06", PD_PETROLEO: 346.939, PD_GAS: 44 }, { id: "7", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-08", PD_PETROLEO: 321.934, PD_GAS: 44 }, { id: "8", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-09", PD_PETROLEO: 351.404, PD_GAS: 44 }, { id: "9", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 360.167, PD_GAS: 44 }, { id: "10", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 371.895, PD_GAS: 44 }, { id: "11", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-11", PD_PETROLEO: 356.232, PD_GAS: 66 }],
    keys = ['FECHA', 'PD_PETROLEO', 'PD_GAS'],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach((k, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(o[k]));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of keys that you want vaues against and `Array.prototype.map()` to achieve this

```js
const data = [{id: "1", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-01", PD_PETROLEO: 369.168, PD_GAS: 96},
       {id: "2", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-02", PD_PETROLEO: 364.21, PD_GAS: 96},
       {id: "3", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-03", PD_PETROLEO: 361.559, PD_GAS: 96},
       {id: "4", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-04", PD_PETROLEO: 322.346, PD_GAS: 81},
       {id: "5", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-05", PD_PETROLEO: 339.027, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "6", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-06", PD_PETROLEO: 346.939, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "7", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-08", PD_PETROLEO: 321.934, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "8", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-09", PD_PETROLEO: 351.404, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "9", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 360.167, PD_GAS: 44},
       {id: "10", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-10", PD_PETROLEO: 371.895, PD_GAS: 44},
      {id: "11", COMPLETAMIENTO: "CYB-003TS", FECHA: "2010-06-11", PD_PETROLEO: 356.232, PD_GAS: 66}];
      
 
 const output = data.map(obj => Object.values(obj));

 // Or you can use your required keys to get respective values
 const output2 = ['FECHA', 'PD_GAS', 'PD_AGUA', 'PD_PETROLEO'].map(key => data.map(obj => obj[key]));
 
 console.log(output2) // `PD_AGUA is in not in input so will show undefined, since question is not showing all data keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
      },
    ];
    var columns = ['id','name'];
    var items = [];
    var newArray = [];
    columns.forEach((col,iter) => {
      items = array.map((v,k) => { return v[col];}); 
      newArray.push(items);  
    });
    console.log(newArray);
```